# VSTO C#/VBA Word Spell Check Events

Tags: c#, vba, automation, vsto, office-interop

Is there a way to detect events Spell Check Start and Spell Check Completed within Word 2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own button to do this with the following VB.NET code for VSTO.

```
    Public Sub SpellCheckButton(ByVal Control As Office.IRibbonControl)
        Try
            Dim result As String = "Spelled incorrectly."

            If Me.Application.CheckSpelling(Me.Range.Text) = True Then
                result = "Spelled correctly."
            End If
            MessageBox.Show(result)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())

        End Try

    End Sub
```